# Morge text files from CLI with sort order and root

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a series of txt files, each with numerous entries. I usually merge all the txt files into one output file using cat, however it becomes a little bit messy because I cannot be sure from which original txt file it came from.

I was wondering if there is a way, using the command line, to first merge all the txt files in alphabetical order and at the same time add the suffix to the original entry to note the file it came from.

For example, let's say I have 2 txt files, each with three entries:

**File_One**:

```
  Alpha
  Bravo 
  Charlie
```

**File_Two**:

```
  Alpha
  Bravo
  Delta
```

What I would like to do is this:

1. Merge the two lists in one output txt file sorted in alphabetical order;
2. Add the suffix to show from which list it comes from:

   ```
      Alpha_File_One
      Alpha_File_Two
      Bravo_File_One
      Bravo_File_Two
      Charlie_File_One
      Delta_File_Two
   ```

Is this possible?

Comment: Use code formatting to format your sample input files and output exactly as they should appear, please.

Comment: Sorry muru not sure what you are asking (i am not a cli expert), but that is how i would like to it be in the output file.

Comment: I am not talking about the CLI. I'm talking about formatting the question. See http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code. Do your files have semicolons, for example?

Comment: Ok, got you.  Made the corrections to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Florian says, you should first add the filename and then sort. Another method is to use `awk`:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s_%s\n", $0, FILENAME}' f1 f2 | sort
Alpha_f1
Alpha_f2
Bravo_f1
Bravo_f2
Charlie_f1
Delta_f2
```

`printf` prints arguments in a specified format, `%s_%s\n` meaning two strings separated by `_` and followed by a newline. `$0` and `FILENAME` contain the current line and filename respectively. I have named the files `f1` and `f2`, in this example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it the other way around: First add the suffix, den merge and sort:

```
(sed 's/$/_File_One/' File_One; sed 's/$/_File_Two/' File_Two) | sort
```